# Какое окончание писать при перечислении?

Tags: перечисление

К таким индивидуально-психологическим особенностям можно отнести: низкую толерантность по отношению к ситуации фрустрации, эмоциональную возбудимость, положительную Я-концепцию, некоторые ценностные ориентации (семья, свобода выбора, здоровье, активная деятельностная жизнь, справедливость),  высокую тревожность, чувствительность к мнению и одобрению окружающих, совестливость, ответственность, консервативность.

Comment: В части склонения ошибок нет,. Ералаш в понятиях.

Comment: И знака вопроса в конце предложения нема.